# React Native BackAndroid doesn't remove the listener

Tags: android, listener, react-native

I'm adding a new listener to BackAndroid on:

```
componentWillMount () {
  BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backAndroidHandler.bind(this));
}
```

and I'm removing the listener on:

```
componentWillUnmount () {
  BackAndroid.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backAndroidHandler);
}

function backAndroidHandler () {
  ...
}
```

but when I unmount the component and mount it again, there are two of the same function and the same event fires twice. Any clue?

Comment: I think a found the problem, at least this has workde so far, when I pass backAndroidHandler.bind(this) I cannot remove the function later, but if I add the function like this: addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backAndroidHandler) and then remove the function, it works. I just have to assign this to something first, like var self = this. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: Maybe is because .bind() creates a new Function ??

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it

```
componentWillMount () {
  this.androidBackHandler = backAndroidHandler.bind(this);
  BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backAndroidHandler);
}

componentWillUnmount () {
  BackAndroid.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.androidBackHandler);
}


function backAndroidHandler () {
  ...
}
```

I tried declaring the function directly on the component but `this` was not binding, it was `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

```
this.androidBackHandler = this.backAndroidHandler.bind(this);
```

It should be like this.